# jQuery Slider f is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Some code...

```
$(function () {
    var select = $("#drp_riskcategory");
    var drpMin = $("#hdnRiskMin").val();
    var drpMax = $("#hdnRiskMax").val();

    $("#slider_riskcategory").slider({
        min: drpMin,
        max: drpMax,
        range: "min",
        value: select[0].selectedIndex + 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
           select[0].selectedIndex = ui.value - 1;
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) { drawChart(false); }
    });
    select.change(function () {
        $('#slider_riskcategory').slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
    });
    $('#slider_riskcategory').slider("value", this.selectedIndex + 1);
});


<body>
    <p>
        <select id="drp_riskcategory" name="drp_riskcategory">
            <option value="5">Defensive</option>
            <option value="6">Cautious</option>
            <option value="7" selected="selected">Balanced</option>
            <option value="8">Capital Growth</option>
            <option value="9">Aggressive</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <div id="slider_riskcategory" style="width:200px">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="5" id="hdnRiskMin" />
    <input type="hidden" value="9" id="hdnRiskMax" />
</body>
```

The above code results in 'f is undefined' when the slider is moved.

The min max values are dynamic and added from code behind, i think this may be my issue

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

JQuery version jquery-1.4.4.min.js

**Resolved**
Turns out the option values were screwing it, set them to range from 1 - 5 rather than 5 - 9 and all was good.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the option values were screwing it, set them to range from 1 - 5 rather than 5 - 9 and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled here from google..Had the same issue, slider didn't move and Firebug reported error "f is undefined".

Dooie's answer led me to right path. Turned out that the value I was setting slider to was NaN..

So if you are getting this same error while trying to move the slider, check your slider's value first!